# update двух таблиц одним запросом

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, помогите сформировать SQL запрос,

> UPDATE news SET display = 0 WHERE display IN(3,4) а так же UPDATE
>   events SET display = 0 WHERE table_id = 1 AND event_id = удаленный
>   news.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так и будет у вас:

```
UPDATE news, events 
SET news.display = 0,
events.display = 0
WHERE news.display IN (3,4)
AND events.table_id = 1 AND events.event_id = удаленный news.id;
```